# IntelliJ IDEA Rebasing Commits window keyboard shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea

I very often do rebasing from IntelliJ IDEA as it is more convenient than command line.

There's one issue though. In the following window:

[image]

I have no idea how can I choose **Action** using **just keyboard**. Is this possible?

IDEA's [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.3/using-git-integration.html#interactive-rebase) does not mention any shortcuts at all, but e.g. `CTRL` + `D` or `ALT` + `UP`/`DOWN` work for me there.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is still opened on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153448